# just got android studio´s latest update and it really broke my installation. What to do?

Tags: android, runtime-error, patch

just go android studio´s latest update and it really broke my installation.

Patch to : Android studio 2.2.2.0 145.3360264

```
 10:40:38 ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in
 class file
 com/intellij/execution/junit2/configuration/JUnitConfigurable 10:40:41
 PicoPluginExtensionInitializationException: Unknown constant tag 250
 in class file
 org/intellij/plugins/intelliLang/inject/config/ui/XmlAttributePanel
 10:40:42 ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in
 class file
 com/intellij/execution/junit2/configuration/JUnitConfigurable 10:40:44
 ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file
 com/intellij/execution/junit2/configuration/JUnitConfigurable 10:40:45
 Plugin Error
          Problems found loading plugins:
          Plugin "Google Analytics Uploader" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.android" not installed.
          Plugin "Android Games" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.android" not installed.
          Plugin "SDK Updater" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.android" not installed.
          Plugin "NDK WorkspaceManager Support" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.android" not installed.
          Plugin "Google Developers Samples" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.android" not installed.
          Plugin "Test Recorder" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.android" not installed.
          Plugin "Google Services" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.android" not installed.
          Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.android" not installed.
          Plugin "Firebase Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "org.jetbrains.android" not installed.
          Disa... (show balloon) 10:41:11 Error Loading Project: Cannot load 3 facets Details... 10:41:12 Plugins Suggestion
          Features covered by IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (Android Support) are detected.
          Check IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition
          Do not suggest Ultimate Edition 10:46:56 Compilation completed successfully with 10 warnings in 13s 654ms 10:47:52
 ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file
 com/intellij/execution/junit2/configuration/JUnitConfigurable 10:48:59
 ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file
 com/intellij/execution/junit2/configuration/JUnitConfigurable
```

UPDATE:
When i go to File>Setttings I get this message and settings is not opening

> 11:16:14 ClassFormatError:
>   org/jetbrains/plugins/groovy/debugger/GroovyHotSwapConfigurableUi

Comment: i've updated AS to 2.2.2 this morning too and i didn't have any problems... Have you searched on the android issues forum if someone else had the same problem?

Comment: no, i will do that thanks. I hade 5 Android Studio windows open all with dif projects. My computer is really powerful so it´s not a problem. I get the feeling it´s because of 5 windows this happens

Comment: If you didn't find a solution yet i suggest you to post the stacktrace on the android forum and see if someone of the Google engineers can help you... i never seen this error before sorry :(.maybe could be an encoding problem of some characters in your code because the error mention a problem with UTF-8

Comment: Just posted an [android issues forum bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225691&thanks=225691&ts=1476956060)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete folder with Android Studio files (Ex: android-studio) and reinstall it from official site [package](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html). Works for me on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 4):

In android studio Go to ***file->settings->plugin-> enable androidsupport***

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting hidden folder `.IntelliJIdea` and reimport your project.

Comment: just search through my win 10 C: drive and no sign of anything *IntelliJIdea**. Yes I have disabled the dont show hidden files system files folder. Do you know where this folder is?

Comment: exemple of path : c:\Users\username\.IntelliJIdea14\   this might help ;) [path depending of OS](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)

Comment: This is residuals, I dont have that folder it must have gone out the window in my Win 10 installation